# How do I use the Radio Button value in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple app in Tkinter but I ran into a problem. I am trying to use the value that is defined with a Radio Button in a function, but it doesn't seem to work. When I press the Button nothing is printed. What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()

window.title("ALL YOU NEED IS EXCEL")

window.geometry('500x200')


variable_1 = StringVar()

rad1 = Radiobutton(window,text='Button 1', value= "Button 1", variable= variable_1)

rad1.grid(column=0, row=4)

rad2 = Radiobutton(window,text='Button 2', value= "Button 2",variable= variable_1)

rad2.grid(column=1, row=4)


def clicked(vrijednost):
    if vrijednost == "Button 1":
        print("This is Button 1")
    
    if vrijednost == "Button 2":
        print("This is Button 2")

btn = Button(window, text="PRINT", height = 2,width = 15, command=clicked(variable_1))

#btn.grid(column=1, row=5)

btn.place(x = 250, y = 150)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the value in the function, you can use `vrijednost = variable_1.get()` inside the function body itself.
Try the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title("ALL YOU NEED IS EXCEL")

window.geometry('500x200')


variable_1 = StringVar()

rad1 = Radiobutton(window,text='Button 1', value= "Button 1", variable= variable_1)

rad1.grid(column=0, row=4)

rad2 = Radiobutton(window,text='Button 2', value= "Button 2",variable= variable_1)

rad2.grid(column=1, row=4)


def clicked():
    vrijednost = variable_1.get()
    if vrijednost == "Button 1":
        print("This is Button 1")
    
    if vrijednost == "Button 2":
        print("This is Button 2")

btn = Button(window, text="PRINT", height = 2,width = 15, command=clicked)

#btn.grid(column=1, row=5)

btn.place(x = 250, y = 150)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just for completeness you can also use `command=lambda: clicked(variable_1.get())`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Adding `StringVar()` parameter.

However, using walrus operator this can be done quite easily.
code:

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title("ALL YOU NEED IS EXCEL")
window.geometry('500x200')

variable_1 = StringVar(window, '1')

rad1 = Radiobutton(window,text='Button 1', value= "Button 1", variable= variable_1)
rad1.grid(column=0, row=4)

rad2 = Radiobutton(window,text='Button 2', value= "Button 2",variable= variable_1)
rad2.grid(column=1, row=4)


def clicked():
    if (vrijednost := variable_1.get()) == "Button 1":
        print("This is Button 1")   
    else:  
        print("This is Button 2")

btn = Button(window, text="PRINT", height = 2,width = 15, command=clicked)
btn.place(x = 250, y = 150)
 
window.mainloop()
```

Output image:

[image]

Output `radiobutton2`

[image]